# Check whether paymentID and PayID isset() in laravel 5.2 using paypal API REST

Tags: php, paypal, laravel-5

I want to check whether paymentID and PayID isset in laravel 5.2. I am finding it challenging to check the variable because the data comes from a url like this.

```
http://localhost:8881/payment/status?success=true&paymentId=PAY-29914071LE6429108K46IF7Y&token=EC-8DT61447BS955762N&PayerID=87ZPPQCLM8G52
```

Currently I can make a call to the Paypal application but i want to check if the data exists in the variable when Paypal response so that my code can continue with the execution.

Here is what i have come up with so far

```
public function getPaymentStatus()
{
    if(isset($_GET['success'], $_GET['paymentID'], $_GET['PayerID'])){
        dd("payment done thanks");
    } 

    return view('payment.paypal_status');
}
```

I have also tried the code in the blade.php but with no success.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code in my controller, getPaymentStatus() function to get the paymentId and PayerID with the Paypal API.

```
$paymentId = Input::get('paymentId');
$PayerID   = Input::get('PayerID');
```

One should be really carefully with the spelling of 'paymentId' and 'PayerID' because thats what really messed me up.